# telerik:RadToggleButton colour change based on selected value

Tags: javascript, telerik

I have multiple telerik:RadToggleButton . This can take fourstates named "", "Yes", "N/A","NO".  I am trying to find a generic code to change the button color based on the text on the button
[image]

Following is my aspx code

```
 <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleB1ops" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                <ToggleStates>
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " />
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" />
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" />
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="N/A" />
                </ToggleStates>
            </telerik:RadToggleButton>
 <telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleA2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px">
                <ToggleStates>
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " />
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" />
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" />
                    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="N/A" />
                </ToggleStates>
            </telerik:RadToggleButton>
```

A javascript code that can work for any toggle button and show green for yes, red for no, and n/a with blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS

```css
<style type="text/css">.Checked {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.notChecked {
  background-color: tan !important;
}

</style>
```

```html
<telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleIntroAprv" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px" meta:resourcekey="btnToggle1Resource1">
  <ToggleStates>
    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource4" CssClass="notChecked" />
    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource5" />
    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" meta:resourcekey="ButtonToggleStateResource6" />
    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="N/A" />
  </ToggleStates>
</telerik:RadToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using icon change for every state with property

```
 PrimaryIconCssClass="yourIcon"
```

As is stated in [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/button/button-types/toggle-button#configure-a-radbutton-control-with-custom-toggle-states).

Also, I would consider a little workaround. You can subscribe to **Click** event on a button and then do simple if:

```
If (btn.Text == "Yes")
{
   btn.Background = Brushes.Green
}
```

and so on.